why react console.log 3 times here
let's look this code:
app.tsx
import "./App.css";
import useHome from './hooks/useHome';

function App() {
  useHome();
  return <></>;
}

export default App;

hooks/useHome.ts
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const query = (): Promise<number> =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 1000),
  );

const useHome = () => {
  const [pageStatus, setPageStatus] = useState<string>("loading");
  const [data, setData] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [deps, setDeps] = useState(data);

  const queryData = async () => {
    setPageStatus("loading");
    try {
      const pageData = await query();
      setData(pageData); // cause second render
      setPageStatus("normal"); // cause third render
    } catch (e) {
      setPageStatus("error");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    queryData(); 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDeps(data); // cause third render 
  }, [data]);

  console.log("@render"); // total 3 times

  return {
    deps,
    data,
    pageStatus,
  };
};

export default useHome;

why '@render' only  console.log  3 times?
I expected it render 4 times;
render first at init,
render second because of  setData
render third because of setPageStatues ( async function environment here )
render forth because of setDeps
but I find it only console 3 times...
Is react merged the setPageStatues and setDeps ?

React batches state updates - https://react.dev/learn/queueing-a-series-of-state-updates

Is there a reason why you're asking? Are you trying to debug something specific about your code?

The console log will trigger each time your component is rerendered. (i.e each time there is a state change in the component)
Additionally initially react will render your component twice in development mode but it will only do it locally and not in production builds.

setData(pageData); // cause second render
setPageStatus("normal"); // cause third render

Your assumption here is mistaken.  These don't each cause a re-render.  These queue/batch their respective state updates.  When the operation is complete, state updates are performed and the component re-renders.

I found that the premise of my problem was in react-native environment. I ran the above code on browser. Indeed, as you said, the two states after await are merged.Sorry, I'll verify it again.

I made a mistake, can you look at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446607/why-react17-do-batch-update-like-this

The answer to your question is: React's batch update mechanism

Initial Render: When your component App mounts, it triggers the useHome hook. At this point, @render logs once.
Triggering queryData via useEffect:
Inside queryData, you first set the pageStatus to "loading", which queues a state update.(not doing it immediately, just queue it)
You then await query() which resolves after 1 second.
After query() resolves, setData is called, queuing another state update.
Immediately after setting data, you set pageStatus to "normal", queuing yet another state update.
So here in such scenarios, React intelligently batches these updates into a single render cycle. Therefore, these changes result in just one render instead of separate renders.
the final (the 3rd render) caused by the setDeps as you already mentioned.


I made a mistake, can you look at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446607/why-react17-do-batch-update-like-this


In React, the rendering process can be optimized by batching state
updates together. This means that multiple state updates within the
same synchronous execution block may be combined into a single render.
Let's break down the scenario and why console.log("@render") is only
called three times instead of four:
Initial Render: This occurs when the component mounts.


Render After setData: When setData(pageData) is called inside
queryData, it triggers a re-render. This is expected behavior.
Render After setPageStatus: Although setPageStatus("normal") is called after setData, React optimizes by batching state updates
together if they occur within the same synchronous execution block.
Since both setData and setPageStatus are called within the same
asynchronous function (queryData), they are likely batched together
and only result in one re-render instead of two separate ones.
Render After setDeps: This effect is triggered by the dependency array [data]. When data changes, setDeps(data) is called, causing a
re-render.


I made a mistake, can you look at this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78446607/why-react17-do-batch-update-like-this
