why react17 do batch update like this?
I find this
App.tsx
import './App.css'
import useHome from './hooks/useHome'

function App() {
  useHome();
  return <div></div>
}

export default App

src/hooks/useHome.ts
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const query = (): Promise<number> =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 1000),
  );

const useHome = () => {
  const [pageStatus, setPageStatus] = useState<string>("loading");
  const [data, setData] = useState<number | null>(null);
  const [nothing , setNothing] = useState(0);
  const [deps, setDeps] = useState(data);

  const queryData = async () => {
    setPageStatus("loading");
    try {
      const pageData = await query();
      setData(pageData); // cause 2nd @render
      setPageStatus("normal"); // cause 3rd @render
      setNothing(1);  // cause 4th @render
    } catch (e) {
      setPageStatus("error");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    queryData(); 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setDeps(data); // cause 3rd @render 
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(()=> {
    console.log('@batch'); // only console 2 times. why react batch update setPageStatus and setDeps ? 
  }, [pageStatus, nothing]);

  console.log("@render"); // total 4 times

  return {
    deps,
    data,
    pageStatus,
  };
};

export default useHome;

In react 17 , because of this async function,  setData(pageData) and setPageStatus('normal') won't batch update . It's meets my expectations. (of cuz its will do batch update in React18)
But i find that setPageStatus('normal') and setDeps(data) batch update together.
Can anyone tell me why? It would be best to have documentation. I didn’t find a corresponding explanation on the official website.

In a way they are two setState calls originating from two separate useEffects in the same execution cycle. As far as I know, state updates in useEffect callbacks are queued up, and flushed at the end of the "Passive Effects" phase once all the useEffect callbacks have completed. Read this: https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2020/05/blogged-answers-a-mostly-complete-guide-to-react-rendering-behavior/#commit-phase-lifecycles

While there is not specific documentation for your case, it is not at all trivial/common. But it is common for React to call stateUpdates from useEffect in batched manner. The same is happening in the second render cycle here. setPageStatus("normal");  and setDeps(data); are being executed as part of two separate useEffects, but after the same render

I can only guess that they entered the same execution cycle, but on the one hand I can't visually observe the cycle they are in. At the same time, we cannot get theoretical support from official documents as to why they do not have a sequential order.
